# Setting the TabIndex value for a dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I want to set the tabIndex property for a row of textbox(s) that are created at run time (dynamically)

My formula is

```
txtFirstName.TabIndex = i * 10 + 1;
txtLastName.TabIndex = i * 10 + 2;
txtEMail.TabIndex = i * 10 + 3;
txtPhone.TabIndex = i * 10 + 4;
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error
*Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
System.Convert.ToInt16( value );
```

for each property set

Answer (score 1):

I is most likely defined as an int.  Multiplying an int by a literal results in an int by default.  You can cast ie tell this is another type using the (Type) cast expression.

```
int I = 5 ; 
short X ; 
X = I; //Error 
I = X; //fine I is larger then X so an implicit cast happens 
X = (short)I ; //also fine
```

Tabindex is a short so you will have to cast.

Answer (score 1):

```
txtFirstName.TabIndex = (short)(i * 10 + 1);
```